# How do you convert a ,crt certificate bundle to PEM using openssl

Tags: openssl

How do you convert a ,crt certificate bundle to PEM using openssl (command line) ?
All the examples if have tried only extract the 1st certificate - I want all certificates in the .crt file to be extracted/converted to a single PEM file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DigiCert tool my friend.